# Vuejs how do you update model's data in model's method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm doing a simple update in the model. when the button is click. it will update the data: message with "Good Bye!" and it work but it revert back to the "Hello Vue.Js!" right away. How do you change the value of the model within its own method?

```
<div id="CreateUser" class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">User Infos</div>
        <div class="panel-body">                
            <label> {{ message }} </label>
            <button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="showAlert">Submit</button>                            
            @{
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FirstName, new {id = "FirstName", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "User First Name"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MiddleName, new {id = "MiddleName", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "User Middle Name"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.LastName, new {id = "LastName", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "User Last Name"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Email, new {@id = "Email", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Email", @type = "email"})
                        <p><b>User Email is also the login account.</b>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Password, new {@id = "Password", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Password", @type = "password"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">                            
                        <button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="showAlert">Submit</button>                            
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Clear"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            }
        </div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function() {
        var app = new Vue({

            el: '#CreateUser',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
            },
            methods: {
                showAlert: function() {
                    this.message = "Good Bye!";
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi @jack, do you mean it changes back when you reload the page?

Comment: Because it works fine with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qq29gs2q/

Comment: I have it wrap inside a form and that cause it to go to a aspnet mvc controller's action but how can it be since i got nothing in the javascript that tell it to go to a controller's action nor did i use beginform.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because form is submitted, so you have to prevent that.There is the `.prevent` modifier that could be used on event

```
<button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="showAlert">Submit</button>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yefexanepe/edit?html,js,output